# how to read back encrypted string from file with php

Tags: php, encryption, fwrite, fread

To store the value of a directory in a `.txt` file I use this encryption:

```
$MainFolderName = 'uploads/folder1';
$key = "raf-key";
$encrypted = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($MainFolderName,'AES-128-CBC', $key));
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($encrypted),'AES-128-CBC',$key);
```

Store the value of `$MainFolderName` encrypted in file `dir.txt`:

```
$actualdir = fopen("dir.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");   
$encrypted = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($MainFolderName,'AES-128-CBC', $key));
fwrite($actualdir, $encrypted);
fclose($actualdir);
```

How can I read back the decrypted value from  `dir.txt` with `fread()`?
I already have this:

```
// Read actual dir from file "dir.txt"
$readdir = fopen("dir.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$dir = fread($readdir,filesize("dir.txt")); // read decrypted value and bind to var $dir
fclose($readdir);
```

Comment: isn't just `$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($dir),'AES-128-CBC',$key);` ?

Comment: no, it can't read the `$encrypted` anymore

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you getting any errors? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I agree! It works. It was my mistake! Thnx for the solution!